# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I just updated to `rails 4.2`. I created a new controller called `home#index` with some minimal html. When I started my `$ rails server` and navigated to `http://localhost:3000/home`, I got `ExecJS RuntimeError`.

P.S.:
I have installed `node.js`, but it still gives me this error.

Comment: Try adding `gem 'therubyracer'` to your `gemfile` and run `undle install`.

Comment: Is `rubyracer` gem uncommented in gemfile?

Comment: I uncommented 'therubyracer' and got this error: `An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.11), and Bundler cannot continue.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. I was trying to integrate `react-rails` and I was using the `jsx` syntax and for some reason the javascript runtime(nodejs) was not able to run this.

-- Cheers